# Keyboard.IsKeyDown always returns true

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, keyboard-events

I have a UI that has inputbindings.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding 
    Key="Up" 
    Command="{Binding Up}" />
```

I want to use this keybinding to scroll down various elements. I could use the in build key-down repeat in windows with a method like this.

```
    public void selectionUp()
    {
        SelectionNo += 1;
    }
```

This works. The selection will move up if i press the up key. However, I do not like the way that the event seems to fire quite slowly at first based on whatever settings the user has for the keyboard repeat in windows. So instead I want to do something like this:

- KeyPressedEvent Hit
- KeyDown bool set to true
- While KeyDown is true

  - +1 to selection
  - Update UI
  - Check Key is still down
  - update KeyDown bool if not

So I ended up with a method like this...

```
        public void positionUp()
    {
        if (!keyUpIsDown) //needed to prevent this while loop being accessed multiple times
        {
            keyUpIsDown = true;
            while (keyUpIsDown)
                {
                SelectionNo += 1;
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.Up))
                {
                    keyUpIsDown = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is that the 'if (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.Up))' always says the key is down even if I have released the key.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you might be failing to allow the message loop to operate and thus the keyup message is never processed - is this code on the UI thread?

Comment: @davidbak That was my thought too. But WPF doesn't have Application.DoEvents so my default answer won't work.

Comment: @davidbak I guess so, if moving the code to a different thread would solve the issue, which code would I move over, and what would be the best way to do that (probably best to post as an answer).. would the UI still update when i change my SelectionNo property?

Comment: Updating the UI when SelectionNo changes is hard to do correctly from a background thread. If my async idea doesn't work, I would try a Timer that runs on the UI thread (e.g. `DispatcherTimer`) .

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to do it in WPF - I answered because this issue - not letting the message loop run 'cause you're spinning in place on the UI thread - is common to all (or nearly all) UI frameworks.  But ... try @JonathanAllen 's answer below - _he_ seems to know WPF!

Comment: I did, a long time ago. But the last time I worked in WPF on anything that wasn't a toy was pre-async/await.

Comment: @hvd While your point is valid in the general case, the type of application he's writing may change the rules. I remember some older games that used the OS settings for delay/repeat and that made the controls rather jerky.

Comment: @JonathanAllen Yeah, there are legitimate reasons for it, but the developer merely declaring "I don't like it" is not one of them.

Comment: @hvd Yes, Jonathan has this right. I specifically do not want the jerky changes over the elements because of these "legitimate reasons", "I don't like it" can be a legitimate reason for software that I am writing for myself as well thanks. Thanks for the -1 and the unconstructive comment.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter why Lewis Heslop is doing it. Anyone else running into this problem won't care so long as it fixes with the Keyboard status. (And they may be looking at something you can't argue with such as the Shift key status.)

Comment: Since it needs to be mentioned, let me re-word my previous comment: ignoring the operating system's repeat rate introduces a serious accessibility problem that makes your application unusable for a portion of your users that may not have full control of their bodies. By your own question, you want to do this simply because you "do not like" it. While valid reasons may exist, this question strongly suggest that you do not have a valid reason. @JonathanAllen Anyone else running into this who may not be aware of the problem should be made aware of it too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it the opportunity to process events from the OS. One way is to make your code asynchronous and add a Task.Delay.

```
  public async void positionUp()
{
    if (!keyUpIsDown) //needed to prevent this while loop being accessed multiple times
    {
        keyUpIsDown = true;
        while (keyUpIsDown)
            {
            SelectionNo += 1;
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.Up))
            {
                keyUpIsDown = false;
            }
            await Task.Delay(100); //you will need to tune this, but it can't be 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and feed back.

Comment: Great stuff.. Worked flawlessly, it appears as through I can even set the delay to 1ms and everything is fine.

Comment: I will give other users a chance to post their ideas before I accept it as an answer!

Comment: Jonathan, In this case, await Task.Yield()  and  away Task.Delay(0) do not seem to work, keyUpIsDown is never set to false.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer.